# What is the recommended way of finding unused functions and procedures in packages?

Tags: sql, oracle, data-dictionary

I have a few packages which begin with the name ´LTR_´. I'm trying to clean up my codebase and would like to find if there are any unused functions and procedures.

Is it possible to query the data-dictionary to find any methods in the `LTR_` packages that are not referenced from anywhere else in the DB? Is this possible without the use of a third-party tool or auditing? Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind functions and procedures can be referenced by SQL coming from outside the database.

Comment: I agree Brian. I've factored that thought in. Thanks.

Comment: Dynamic SQL won't show up either.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla:If you're using Oracle 11g ,then you can use `DBA_IDENTIFIERS` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all references with
`select * from all_source where upper(text) like '%LTR_METHODNAME%'`